# How can I get Toads of different colors?

Tags: super-mario-run

After understanding the basics of Super Mario Run, I've found that my amount of red Toads is rising steadily. However, I do not have any other colored Toads which are needed to unlock most of the other buildings and decorations.

Is it possible to get the full variety of Toads, or is it simply impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are found in the other levels of the game, past World 1. It depends on which levels you play. The other Toads you can get by buying the $10 upgrade, which includes Worlds 2-6, so you can get the other colored Toads.

Comment: Thanks, I've not bought the game so it looks like I'm not getting the other Toads any time soon

Comment: I plan on doing that!!! Can't wait! I've played the free demo so much I have almost 300 red Toads.